# Custom alert rules with Application Insights

Tags: monitoring, azure-application-insights

Need the help of the crowd.

I'm wondering if the below monitoring scenario is possible with Application Insights.

I want to have an alert if one event occurred (on a certain entity) but another event *did not* follow it.

We have a job scheduling machine, we want to monitor cases in which a job creation was requested but a job was not created.

So we log everything of course, we have an event that a job was requested, and we have an event when a job was created.

And we want to be alerted if jobs were requested but was not created.

What would be the best practice? Is it even possible to AI?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I now found there is a way to define alerts on custom log searches.

We will give it a try and keep this post updated.

If anyone has other ideas - lets me know.